# Dynamic object properties in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do i create dynamic properties on an object in objective-c?
in ActionScript we can do something like this

```
var obj : Object;
obj[ "myDynamicProperty" ] = true;
trace( obj.myDynamicProperty );
```

How would i do this in objective-c?

I have tried the following

```
NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[obj setValue:@"labelValue" forKey:@"label"];
```

But that just throws a runtime error.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

`Objects-NSObjects`, to be specific-in `Objective-C` do not allow arbitrary properties to be set on them using `KVC`; that is, they are not key-value containers.  If you want something that can accept arbitrary key-value pairs, use a dictionary (`NSMutableDictionary`).

You could also use the associated objects API if you are comfortable enough dropping down to the `Obj-C` runtime. Search for `objc_setAssociatedObject` in the documentation to see how you can use this `API`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need custom behavior in addition to arbitrary properties, you can create a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) object. Make your own custom class that contains an `NSMutableDictionary` instance variable, then write your own methods that simply call `setValue:forKey:` and so forth on that internal dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Objective-C don't normally work this way. It is possible with [runtime functions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject), but resorting to runtime functions is awkward and generally not idiomatic. If you want an arbitrary key-value store, use NSMutableDictionary.

In general, it's good practice in Objective-C so that every object has a fixed set of properties instead of tacking them on *ad hoc* like we sometimes do in ActionScript/Javascript.